# Assembly Programming I can't give the al register to the _printf as argument

Tags: macos, assembly

I have limited knowledge in Assembly Programming. 
In this simple code I've tinkered with the `al` and `ah` and tried to print the value of `al` using `_printf`
I've taken the prologue, epilogue and `_printf` related codes from random places. I don't have full command over them. I'm just trying to see the result of my tinkering.

```
section .data
msg   db  "Answer: %c", 0x0a, 0x00 ;What do the 0x0a and 0x00 mean?
; Considering that al 1 byte long, so I've chosen the %c (char) inside _printf
section .text       ;

global _main        ; 
extern _printf, _exit   ; 

_main:           ; 
    push ebp     ; 
    mov ebp, esp ; 
    sub esp, 5   ; 


    mov al, 2   ; Here are my test lines 
    shl al, 1   ; 
    mov ah, al  ;
    shl al, 2   ;
    add ah, al  ;
    shl al, 1   ;
    add al, ah  ; The end result is stored in al


    mov byte[esp+4], al   ; al as argument to msg  
    mov dword[esp], msg   ;
    call _printf      ;


    xor eax, eax          ; 
    mov esp, ebp      ; 
    pop ebp               ; 
    ret                   ; 


; Build (macOS, 32bit)
; nasm -f macho shift.asm -o shift.o
; ld -macosx_version_min 10.8 -no_pie -arch i386 -o shift shift.o -lc
```

Compiles and links fine but gives `Segmentation fault: 11` error.

How to arrange it so that it prints the value of `al` correctly ?

Comment: "What do the 0x0a and 0x00 mean?" `0x0a` is a newline code and `0x00` is the line terminating code.  
You should keep your stackpointer dword aligned, therefore subtract a multiple of 4.

Comment: `sub esp,5` You should maintain _at least_ 4 byte alignment with the stack pointer, so `sub esp,8` would be better.  Or you don't need that at all, as you can use `push` to save the arguments to the `printf` call onto the stack (then clean them up with `add esp,8` when the call returns).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you're only interested in `AL`, you can print a regular integer from `EAX`. It'll just have a small numerical value.

```
mov al, 2   ; Here are my test lines 
shl al, 1   ; 
mov ah, al  ;
shl al, 2   ;
add ah, al  ;
shl al, 1   ;
add al, ah  ; The end result is stored in al
movzx eax, al  ; -> EAX=52
push eax
push msg
call _printf
add  esp, 8
xor eax, eax
ret
```

Comment: Or pass a `%hhu` format string to indicate a `uint8_t`, to ask printf to ignore high garbage in the 4-byte arg.  Or `%hhd` for `int8_t` would be equivalent to sign-extending with movsx for a `%d` conversion.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've applied the suggested changes but it still gave the same error i.e. `Segmentation fault: 11` Note: I've changed the line `sub esp, 5` to `sub esp, 8` too, to make the stack to adjust for the `eax`

Comment: Update. After I removed the 11th line `sub esp, 8` as per the suggestion by the @1201ProgramAlarm, and changed the _printf's argument to `%hhd` as suggested by @Peter Cordes, it started to give the `Answer: 52` line. That's fine but after it it keeps on giving the `Segmentation fault: 11` error.

Comment: @LarsMalmsteen: Use a debugger to find out which instruction is faulting.  Just getting a segfault doesn't tell you nearly as much.  (But if it's after printf returns, probably you messed up the stack somehow, like maybe you didn't `add esp,8` to pop the args you pushed?  Remember that `ret` pops a return address.)